# Create an array with given median, mean, mode, and range

Tags: java, arrays, math, mean, median

I already know how to calculate the median, mean, mode from an array in Java. But is there actually a way to do the reverse like creating an array from the median, mode, mean, given the range and the number of numbers in the array ?

The numbers in the array can be created by randomness as long as it satisfies the condition above. It can stop when successfully find the first array with that condition. And plus the range can be from 0 to 10 or 0 to 100, not so much.

Comment: This is a math question, not a programming question: how to create a set that satisfies a certain median, mean, mode and range criteria.

Comment: Yes there is a way to do that.

Comment: What do you mean with your question? Is your question "Is doing this possible"? It would be helpful for you to share some code above that you wrote trying to solve this problem

Comment: If you want to maximize randomness, your program would be rather complicated.

Comment: This IS a programming question, unless you know of a way to do this by hand...and even if you did, why do it by hand when it could be handled by a program. Definitely some math involved too :)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about mathematics.

Answer (score 1):

Yes / No

When you do an array to mmm, you are applying a lossy algorithm, you are losing the original data.

There can be literally an infinite number of array combinations that would result in the same `mmm`.

Answer (score 0):

Some naive ideas

Median: for example your array have 2n+1 elements, put n elements which are less than your median, n elements which are greater than median;

Mean: say your array have m elements, Sum = m * Mean, generate m elements by partitioning Sum;

Mode: count the frequency of the numbers you put into the array, make sure Mode has the highest frequency;